# UITextView - anyway to figure out if entire string is visible?

Tags: ios, uitextview

I'm wondering, is there anyway to figure out if the entire string is visible within a `UITextView`? (without measuring the size of the string itself since the `UITextView` is an irregular shape).

Comment: @MiloGosnell - I changed it to say "anyway to figure out if entire string is visible?"

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite know what you mean about TextView being an irregular shape, though I've written a method which returns a BOOL result to let you know if the string will be visible or not. If you set the font attributes you're using within this, it works out the calculation based on them.

```
-(BOOL)isStringFullyVisibleWithinTextViewWithString:(NSString*)yourString{

    CGSize textViewSizeOversize = CGSizeMake(textView.frame.size.width, textView.frame.size.height+100);

    NSDictionary *stringAttributes = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:13] forKey: NSFontAttributeName];

    CGSize stringAreaSize = [yourString boundingRectWithSize:textViewSize options:NSStringDrawingTruncatesLastVisibleLine|NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin attributes:stringAttributes context:nil].size;

    CGFloat stringAreaHeight = stringAreaSize.height;

    if (stringAreaHeight < textView.frame.size.height){
      return YES;
    }

    return NO;
}
```

I'm not aware of any solution that would return the answer you're looking for without measuring the string (which of course this method does).

I hope this helps,

Cheers,
Jim.